# What does Go's pprof stand for?

Tags: go, naming-conventions, naming, pprof, go-toolchain

`pprof` is a profiling tool of Go. But what does the word `pprof` stand for?

It might be a silly question but I can't get an answer of it from anywhere.

[Google's pprof source code](https://github.com/google/pprof)

[Go blog article about pprof](https://blog.golang.org/pprof)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [godoc](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/pprof?tab=doc) for the package: **P**erformance **prof**iles.

> pprof is a tool for collection, manipulation and visualization of performance profiles.